# TypeScript failing to generate objects in the context of Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm attempting to test my React app via Jest. When I run the following command to run my tests, `jest` I get the following error:

```
Debug Failure. False expression: Output generation failed

      1 | import * as TestData from 'TestModule';
      2 |
    > 3 | export class TestDataEmitter {
      4 |       constructor() { }
      5 |       public emit() {
      6 |               return TestData.data;

      at Object.transpileModule (node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93386:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (component.ts:3:67)
```

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
|   component.ts
|   package.json
|   tree.txt
|   tsconfig.json
|   typings.d.ts
|   yarn-error.log
|   yarn.lock
|             
\---test
        test.ts
```

The relevant files:

> typings.d.ts

```
declare interface TestInterface {
    id: number;
    data: string;
}

declare module 'TestModule' {
    const testData: TestInterface;
    export = testData;
}
```

> component.ts

```
import * as TestData from 'TestModule';

export class TestDataEmitter {
    constructor() { }
    public emit() {
        return TestData.data;
    }
}
```

> test/test.ts

```
import * as TestData from 'TestModule';

export class TestDataEmitter {
    constructor() { }
    public emit() {
        return TestData.data;
    }
}
```

> package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
        "jest": "^22.4.3",
        "ts-jest": "^22.4.2",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "testRegex": "tests?(?:\\|/)(?:(?!helpers?).*(?:\\|/))*.*[Tt]ests?.*\\.tsx?",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "TestModule": "<rootDir>/typings.d.ts"
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `moduleNameMapper` object, I instead get "Cannot find module 'TestModule' from 'component.ts'".

Here's a git repo with the above files in it: https://github.com/morganthrapp/jest-mcve

Comment: Not sure if that can be of help, but have you seen this? https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/136#issuecomment-287734173

Comment: I had not seen that. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have done anything. My error happens even without the `--coverage`.

Comment: Can you provide all of this in a git repo? Would be faster to debug and provide you a solution

Comment: @TarunLalwani Sure, this should have have everything in it. https://github.com/morganthrapp/jest-mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have the typings for the `TestModule`, but there is no implementation of that module. The [moduleNameMapper](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) should be used to add stubs of a module.

The emit function is unable to find the implementation of the TestModule. Create an empty file `testModule` and change the mapper config to

```
"TestModule": "<rootDir>/testModule.ts".
```

Now the test will resolve the module and since the file is empty, `TestModule.data` would be `undefined`.

Apologies if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly my problem. It looks like SPFx creates the module in the background, but it's not available in the context of unit testing.